# Open ports test with telnet - connection

Tags: linux

Hi
    I try to test open ports with telnet client. Unfortunately I get error:

[root@localhost ~]# telnet 127.0.0.1
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused

For 1500 port:

[root@localhost ~]# telnet 127.0.0.1 1500
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
[root@localhost ~]#

My /etc/hosts file:

127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

I flushed iptables, and I have UP LOOPBACK RUNNING.

How could I fix it to connect and test ports?

Thanks a lot for replies.
Regards

Comment: Evidently there is nothing listening to ports 23 and 1500 on your machine, there is nothing to fix.

Comment: Do you want to enable Telnet?

Comment: Thanks, yes this is reason. I thought, that connect telnet client can open port, but it only connect to just opened port? My another question, related with this topis: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107100/check-all-available-ports-even-currently-closed

Answer (score 1):

You need a service to listen on those ports, otherwise tools like telnet cannot connect to them.